# Python rename file based on file in same directory

Tags: python, rename

I have a file directory structure like this:

/folder

- aaa.pdf
- bbb.xml
- stamped.pdf

Where PDF and XML file names have no patterns to them, except that every folder has stamped.pdf in it (stamped.pdf needs to be ignored).

I want to rename the .xml file in the directory to match the .pdf file name, so I end up with:

/folder

- aaa.pdf
- aaa.xml
- stamped.pdf

Python so far (not renaming anything yet, just trying to get the filenames at this point)

```
import os

pdf = ('.pdf')
xml = ('.xml')
stamped = ('stamped.pdf')

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('folder'):
print('The current folder is ' + folderName)

for filename in filenames:
    namefile =  os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    if (filename.endswith(pdf) and filename != stamped):
      pdfname = namefile
      print('PDF File Name: ' + pdfname)
    if filename.endswith(xml):
      print('RENAME XML FILE NAME: ' + namefile + 'TO: ' pdfname)
    else:
      print('')


print('')
```

Right now I'm just printing values before I get into the renaming.

In the script above, pdfname is undefined in the XML conditional, because the pdfname variable isn't set/available in the XML conditional.

How can I pass the pdfname variable so that it can be used to rename the XML file in the same directory?

Thanks!

Comment: except the `stamped.pdf` file, do you always have 1 pdf file in each folder?

Comment: Once you have the respective name stored in a variable you can use that to rename the file in the respective directory using e.g. `os.rename('b.xml', variable + '.xml')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for parent, _, files in os.walk('.'):
    if not files:
        continue
    pdf_file = None
    xml_file = None
    for filename in files:
        if filename.lower().endswith('.pdf') and filename.lower() != 'stamped.pdf':
            pdf_file = filename
        elif filename.lower().endswith('.xml'):
            xml_file = filename
    new_xml_filename = '{}/{}.xml'.format(parent, os.path.splitext(pdf_file)[0])
    xml_file = '{}/{}'.format(parent, xml_file)
    if os.path.exists(new_xml_filename):
        print('cannot rename %s without overwriting an existing file. skipping' % xml_file)
        continue
    else:
        os.rename(xml_file, new_xml_filename)
        print('renamed {} -> {}'.format(xml_file, new_xml_filename))
```